# Can't install a image file anymore, what's wrong?

Tags: qt4, qmake

In the old days, I use the following config to install a image file along with `make install`,

```
icon.files = images/udv.png
icon.path = $${PREFIX}/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/

INSTALLS += icon
```

Now I got an error,

`strip:/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/udv.png: File format not recognized`

Clearly qmake take it as a executable, any work arounds?

Version in use:

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.4 in /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your image file has an executable bit set which fools Qt into thinking its an executable. See [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3171). A quick solution would be running

```
chmod -x images/udv.png
```

to remove the executable bit from the image file.